# Plotar Grafíco Barras Multiplas Variáveis em R

Tags: r

Preciso montar um gráfico no R a partir de uma tabela em CSV em barras da seguinte maneira: O eixo Y é referente a contagem total de cada variável(coluna) no eixo X. Sendo o Y o número de pessoas e o X várias colunas da tabela. Os exemplos que eu achei só usam o gráfico em barras pra expressar frequência, o que não é a minha necessidade.
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se entendi o formato dos seus dados. Parece que você tem algumas colunas preenchidas com contagens de pessoas em diferentes observações, e quer a soma de cada coluna no gráfico. Se for isso, é bem simples:

Primeiro, criei alguns dados aleatórios:

```
dados <- replicate(5, sample(1:10, 5, TRUE))
colnames(dados) <- paste0("Col", 1:5)
dados
#     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
#[1,]    9    3    1    8    8
#[2,]    3    9    3    5   10
#[3,]    4   10    2    8    3
#[4,]    6    7    7   10    7
#[5,]   10    7    4    4    2
```

Para fazer o gráfico, basta plotar a soma das colunas:

```
barplot(colSums(dados))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É exatamente isso. Só esqueci de mencionar uma coisa. Essa tabela tem várias colunas e eu quero selecionar apenas algumas delas. Onde eu especifico isso?

Comment: @GilbertoKreisler Você pode especificar as colunas pelo nome, por exemplo: `barplot(colSums(dados[,c("Col1", "Col3")]))` ou pela ordem: `barplot(colSums(dados[,c(1, 3)]))`. Você pode ainda calcular a soma de todas colunas e então pegar apenas os valores de interesse. O resultado não muda, mas a lógica sim: `barplot(colSums(dados)[c("Col1", "Col3")])`ou `barplot(colSums(dados)[c(1,3)])`.

Comment: Quando eu usei a segunda lógica deu um erro:    **Erro em colSums(data) : 'x' deve ser numérico'**  . Na primeira lógica, que funciona, quando plota o gráfico uma barra aparece sem o nome da coluna referente e em outras é o contrário. Não sei se as barras que não aparecem tem a ver com a disparidade dos valores, se for, tem como fazer algo pra elas aparecerem? Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @GilbertoKreisler O erro deve ter ocorrido porque você tem colunas de texto também, então o ideal é utilizar a primeira alternativa. Os nomes não aparecendo provavelmente são apenas por falta de espaço. Tente ver o gráfico em uma janela maior e o problema deve ser resolvido.

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa para a resposta do @Molx, mas seguindo o conceito
`tidy data`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

dados <- replicate(5, sample(1:10, 5, TRUE))
colnames(dados) <- paste0("Col", 1:5)

dados_tidy <- dados %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  gather("Coluna", "Valor", 1:5)

head(dados_tidy)

##   Coluna Valor
## 1   Col1     4
## 2   Col1     6
## 3   Col1    10
## 4   Col1     7
## 5   Col1     5
## 6   Col2     5

dados_tidy %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Coluna, Valor)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
dados_tidy %>% 
  filter(Coluna %in% c("Col1","Col3", "Col5")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Coluna, Valor)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]